# Must use destructuring props assignment while pushing to another screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push, navigator

I am trying to navigate from login screen to dashboard screen in React Native.

But, It's throwing following error.

```
Must use destructuring props assignment [react/destructuring-assignment]
```

my code is

```
loginMethod() {
//some code
if (Success) {
          this.props.navigator.push({
            Component: Dashboard
          });
        this.state.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{
      Component: Dashboard
    }]);

}

}
```

I am very new to React Native, Any suggestion?

Comment: `this.state.props`? are you saving entire `props` in `state`?

Comment: I am just trying after login success, navigating to dashboard. I am very new to react native. After navigate to dashboard, there should not be back button.

Comment: `this.state.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack` ????  just use `this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack`

Comment: Must use destructuring props assignment

Answer (score 0):

Thats a ESLint error. You can fix it by extracting `navigator` into separate variable.

```
loginMethod() {
  //some code
  if (Success) {
     const { navigator } = this.props;

     navigator.push({
        Component: Dashboard
     });
  }
}
```

This should fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a eslint error. you need to change your code.  use destructuring

```
 loginMethod() {
    //some code
    if (Success) {
             // using destructuring
              const {navigator} = this.props;
              navigator.push({
                Component: Dashboard
              });    
              navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{
                Component: Dashboard
             }]);
    }       
}
```

Comment: after               navigator.push({
this line its showing error can not convert nsmutabledictionary to nsstring in simulator.